# Alternative method to Switch to make code more stable in Vb.net

Tags: vb.net

I have a code which is a type of a filter showing the elements according the combobox's selected index. I'm using Select Case method, but it seems it's insufficient method to apply.

If `autoMBS.tlbCheckBodyCompCtrl_cmb_substrlvl.SelectedIndex=0` it will be do nothing

If `autoMBS.tlbCheckBodyCompCtrl_cmb_substrlvl.SelectedIndex=1` it will be show only group 1

If `autoMBS.tlbCheckBodyCompCtrl_cmb_substrlvl.SelectedIndex=2` it will be show group 1 + group 2

If `autoMBS.tlbCheckBodyCompCtrl_cmb_substrlvl.SelectedIndex=3` it will be show group 1 + group 2 + group 3

As you see in below code there's lots of duplication in code to show it.

```
 Public Shared Sub checkGetBodies(ByVal SpckModel As IScrModel, ByVal SpckClass As String)
        Dim Bodies As IScrNamedObjectList
        Bodies = SpckModel.getBodyList(False)
        checkListBodies(Bodies, autoMBS.dgvCheckBodyComp, SpckClass)
        autoMBS.tlbCheckBodyCompCtrl_cmb_filt.Items.Add(SpckClass)
        If autoMBS.tlbCheckBodyCompCtrl_cmb_substr.SelectedIndex = 2 Then
            Dim SubstrsLvL1 As IScrNamedObjectList
            Dim SubstrLvL1 As IScrSubstructure
            Dim nSubstrLvL1 As Integer
            Dim SubstrsLvL2 As IScrNamedObjectList
            Dim SubstrLvL2 As IScrSubstructure
            Dim nSubstrLvL2 As Integer
            Dim SubstrsLvL3 As IScrNamedObjectList
            Dim SubstrLvL3 As IScrSubstructure
            Dim nSubstrLvL3 As Integer

            Select Case autoMBS.tlbCheckBodyCompCtrl_cmb_substrlvl.SelectedIndex
                Case 0
                Case 1
                    SubstrsLvL1 = SpckModel.getSubstrList(False)
                    nSubstrLvL1 = SubstrsLvL1.count
                    If nSubstrLvL1 > 0 Then
                        For x As Integer = 0 To nSubstrLvL1 - 1
                            SubstrLvL1 = SubstrsLvL1.item(x)
                            checkGetSubstrBodies(SubstrLvL1, SubstrLvL1.name)
                        Next
                    End If
                Case 2
                    SubstrsLvL1 = SpckModel.getSubstrList(False)
                    nSubstrLvL1 = SubstrsLvL1.count
                    If nSubstrLvL1 > 0 Then
                        For x As Integer = 0 To nSubstrLvL1 - 1
                            SubstrLvL1 = SubstrsLvL1.item(x)
                            checkGetSubstrBodies(SubstrLvL1, SubstrLvL1.name)

                            SubstrsLvL2 = SubstrLvL1.getSubstrList(False)
                            nSubstrLvL2 = SubstrsLvL2.count
                            If nSubstrLvL2 > 0 Then
                                For y As Integer = 0 To nSubstrLvL2 - 1
                                    SubstrLvL2 = SubstrsLvL2.item(y)
                                    checkGetSubstrBodies(SubstrLvL2, SubstrLvL2.name)
                                Next
                            End If
                        Next
                    End If
                Case 3
                    SubstrsLvL1 = SpckModel.getSubstrList(False)
                    nSubstrLvL1 = SubstrsLvL1.count
                    If nSubstrLvL1 > 0 Then
                        For x As Integer = 0 To nSubstrLvL1 - 1
                            SubstrLvL1 = SubstrsLvL1.item(x)
                            checkGetSubstrBodies(SubstrLvL1, SubstrLvL1.name)

                            SubstrsLvL2 = SubstrLvL1.getSubstrList(False)
                            nSubstrLvL2 = SubstrsLvL2.count
                            If nSubstrLvL2 > 0 Then
                                For y As Integer = 0 To nSubstrLvL2 - 1
                                    SubstrLvL2 = SubstrsLvL2.item(y)
                                    checkGetSubstrBodies(SubstrLvL2, SubstrLvL2.name)

                                    SubstrsLvL3 = SubstrLvL2.getSubstrList(False)
                                    nSubstrLvL3 = SubstrsLvL3.count
                                    If nSubstrLvL3 > 0 Then
                                        For z As Integer = 0 To nSubstrLvL3 - 1
                                            SubstrLvL3 = SubstrsLvL3.item(z)
                                            checkGetSubstrBodies(SubstrLvL3, SubstrLvL3.name)
                                        Next
                                    End If
                                Next
                            End If
                        Next
                    End If
            End Select
        End If

    End Sub
```

Comment: The complexity is not coming from the Switch-statement but the fact that you are not using functions to call but copying the same codefragment in multiple places. Also this seems to be a classical example of a situation where recursive function (function that calls itself, multiple times if needed) should be used since as your levels grow, you have the ***same logic*** even more times.

Comment: Learn how to use array or list. Then, you'll see how all of this case and if-in-in can be converted to a simple for loop. If the code is working well as is, I suggest you post it on codereview.stackexchange.com/ instead

Comment: The simplest fix is to ditch the Select Case statement completely and only keep the Case 3 code.  Add If-statements to that code to check the SelectedIndex.

Comment: @Esko you're right same logic, but i'didn't find a exact solution how to achieve this problem.

Comment: @the_lotus thanks for the feedback i dont know how to handle this types. I'm using so much cascaded if statements.

Comment: You're repeating the show-group-1 and show-group-2 code, which should probably be pulled out into separate functions (and then it would also make sense to pull the show-group-3 code out into a separate function as well for clarity).  If you make that change, I think your `Select Case` will be a lot more straightforward; there would still be some additional potential refactoring, but it would be a lot less urgent to do.